# Bringing a control and its children to front in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a layering system which uses panels to contain different controls and GDI drawings, but I would like to change the order that they are displayed. I have used the `BringToFront()` method on the panel, this does bring it to the front, but the controls that I have added to it are still displayed behind the other controls. Is there a way that I can bring these controls up as well?

Thanks.

## EDIT:

I should add that these panels are transparent. And I add controls to the panel like `panelName.Controls.Add(newControl);`

Comment: Can you show how you are adding controls to panel?

Comment: You must not added controls to panel because if you did, when you bring panel to front, the controls would be on it.

Comment: Just made an experiment, definitely, if control is placed on the panel, `panel1.BringToFront();` will bring panel with its controls upfront. So, look, if your controls actually dropped on the panel. Sometimes you drop them so that panel sits behind but the control belongs to a form.

Answer (score 0):

You may sort the whole collection of child controls of your panel, to change the order in which they are displayed.

```
Panel panel; //your top-most panel; this can be as well a Form

for (int i = 0; i < panel.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(
        panel.Controls[i], panel.Controls.Count - 1 - i
    );
}
```

To keep this example simple the collection will be sorted in reversed order, but you are free to add any logic to calculate a new child index which fits your needs.
Obviously, the key here is the `SetChildIndex` method ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), allowing you to rearrange a controls index in the collection.

If you only want to sort objects of the type `Panel` (or another single type), then there is a quicker way to do so using LINQ:

```
List<Panel> sorted = panel.Controls.OfType<Panel>().ToList();
sorted.Sort((p1, p2) => p1.TabIndex.CompareTo(p2.TabIndex));
panel.Controls.Clear();
panel.Controls.AddRange(sorted.ToArray());
```

This sorts all the panels comparing their tab index (just as an example). Should be easy to change this for other properties.

Another most common "mistake" lies in your `*.Designer.cs`-file. When dropping controls onto a form/panel, the order may have been reversed. Just take a look at your designer generated file and take look at the order.

Answer (score -1):

You could loop through the list of controls on the panel ( contained within Panel.Controls ), and bring those to the front as well.

Example:
- Lets say you have a Panel p1 with 3 buttons b1, b2, and b3.

to bring p1 to the front and all it's controls you would do:

```
p1.BringToFront();
foreach(var c in p1.Controls){ c.BringToFront();}
```

Comment: This is not needed, unless you want to bring one panel child control in front of another child. If you bring panel to front, it will have all the controls on it as well. What your code will do is create havoc in control hierarchy.